# angular 5, how to get id of a selected

Tags: forms, angular5, select-options

I get an array of objects from data

```
[{id: 324, name: "name1"}, {id: 4534, name: "name2"}, {id: 3436654, name: "name3"}]
```

I show only obj.name on a form on html (no obj.id) . By clicking on select option on a form, I select a obj.name. How can I get an id of a selected obj.name in component.ts file without showing it on html file?

Answer (score -2):

You can use an ngfor and a click event:

```
<div *ngFor="for object in array">
    <span (click)="select(object.id)">{{object.name}}</span>
<div>
```